# SQL Server 2016 table access

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET MVC5 with some forms for data entry and I have a database with 30 users.

3 of them are Admin, 4 of them are Regional Managers and the rest are users by country.

**1.** I want to restrict the users by country access to some fields in a form. Basically, there are 4 fields that only the Regional Managers can see and introduce data.

Also there's another form that only the Regional Managers can have access.

**2.** When the users logs into the application, they should only be able to see the data regarding the country they belong to. Example: a user from China can only see and introduce data from Chinese projects and a user from Indonesia can only do the same for projects in Indonesia.

How can I implement these restrictions in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should implement `Roles` in your application and take care of that when they login.

Comment: I agree with @WEI_DBA. this is not a sql server thing, it should be handled in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring about that restriction at the application end and not in SQL Server. The app devs should implement that logic in place.

Additionally, what you could do at the database end would be to restrict users to access specific data only. One way of implementing this would be to create separate views for each country and grant users access to those views and not to the parent table directly. A user from japan could be granted access only to the view that holds data for Japan.